# Unix tcsh - alias using command line argument $1 versus \!:1

Tags: unix, tcsh

In Unix (tcsh), I've referenced command line arguments in my aliases with two different notations - `$1` and `\!:1`.

But I noticed that if I try to save `$1` to an environment variable, it doesn't get saved. However `\!:1` does get saved.

```
alias hear 'setenv x \!:1 && echo $x'
--> hear that
that
--> echo $x
that

alias oh 'setenv x $1 && echo $x'
--> oh no
no
--> echo $x
```

Nothing shows up on the echo of $x when $1 is used to store the value.  What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`$1` returns the first argument passed **to the script** that contains the `alias` command. So if you are calling it from the command line, it will return nothing.

`\!:1` returns the first argument passed **to the aliased command**, so that is clearly what you should be using.

Comment: Thanks for answer.  That's exactly what I'm looking for.  Your personal webpage link in your profile is broken.

Answer (score 7):

supergra has answered the primary point, but it may leave you wondering why you see your text echoed back to you even though the variable was not set. That is, you have `echo $x` at the end of your alias, and indeed you see `no` when you enter `oh no`, but that does not mean that echo is echoing the variable.

What is happening there is that `echo` is printing the (empty) variable, but then `echo` is also catching the "no" part *separately*. If you do `alias tmp 'echo $1'` and try `tmp hi` you will print "hi" because it's as if you did "echo $1 hi".

To see this more clearly, try `alias tmp 'echo abc $1 def '` and do `tmp hi` again, and you will print "abc  def hi". Again, if you try `alias tmp 'echo $1 & which '` and use it again you should, unless you have a command named `hi`, see something like "hi: Command not found." or if you do `tmp ls` you will see the output of `which ls`.

One more example: try `alias tmp 'echo $1 & '` and `tmp hi` to see that it actually tries to execute `hi` as if it were a command, which can be dangerous if you were not expecting that.

Comment: Strangely enough, I did have that question after reading the accepted answer.