# How can you use multiple argv elements in an alias using tcsh?

Tags: unix, tcsh

I'm making an alias to just rename a file. I have the following alias:

```
alias change 'mv argv[1] argv[2]'
```

I have a file in my directory called `calendar`. When I enter

```
change calendar new_cal
```

I want the filename to change to `new_cal`. Instead, it returns

```
mv: No match.
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
alias change 'mv \!:1 \!:2'
```

`$argv` gets you the arguments passed **to the script**, while `\!:1` and `\!:2` will get you the first and second arguments passed **to this command**.

Also see [Unix tcsh - alias using command line argument $1 versus \!:1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470619/unix-tcsh-alias-using-command-line-argument-1-versus-1/20600609)